# NSAttributedString.Key,Link not working on ios 11.4

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsattributedstring, uitextviewdelegate

I have a `UITextView` that works great in iOS 12 and 13 but not on iOS 11.4 and below.

This textView has a text that 2 parts need to be clickable and open a webview (the common Privacy Policy and Terms & Conditions text).

```
let attributedLegalString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "sign_up_terms_of_use".localized())
        if let rangePrivacy = "sign_up_terms_of_use".localized().lowercased().rangeOfSubstring("profile_privacy_policy".localized().lowercased()) {
            attributedLegalString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: NSURL(string: "https://XXX/privacy-policy")!, range: rangePrivacy)
            attributedLegalString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: AppFontName.fontType.H1.value, range: rangePrivacy)
        }
        if let rangeTerms = "sign_up_terms_of_use".localized().lowercased().rangeOfSubstring("login_terms_of_use".localized().lowercased()) {
            attributedLegalString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "https://XXX/terms-conditions", range: rangeTerms)
            attributedLegalString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: AppFontName.fontType.caption.value, range: rangeTerms)
        }
```

Then I have this method:

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        self.openWebsite(url: URL)
        return false
    }

    func openWebsite(url: URL) {
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        safariVC.delegate = self
    }
```

This works great except for iOS 11. Any clue?

The textView data Detector is selected for Link. And the change of color works fine so the Range is correct.

Comment: Your code is strange because you use `NSURL`, wouldn't it much better to use `URL` in Swift (if available, which it is in your version), and for legals, you set the value a URL, and the terms, you set the value as a String. Are both not working?

Comment: @Larme about the string and the NSURL, they both should work (and work in iOS 13). I did different way because I was debugging trying to see if passing the NSURL fixed the issue, but it didn't. Sorry, I know it's confusing.

Comment: There was a bug in NSAttributedString, I don't remember the iOS impacted version, but check if you add an "invisible" effect applied to all the attributedString and check if it works.